# Add packages to Ubuntu Distro installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, scripts

I wanna create small change to Ubuntu Install CD. I want to add a few packages so when Ubuntu is installing, those packages also would be installed. So I wondering if it has some maybe post-installation script?

All this just for personal use. I need to install same software on about 30 computer and I want to automate this process as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you make all the changes you want on one computer then make a system image of it and apply it to the other 29 computers. I suggest you use CloneZilla.

Comment: While this theoretically answers the question, it would be better to give more explanation of why it would be a better choice and some basic info about how to get and use CloneZilla.

Comment: All computer should have same hardware?

Comment: @arhimed I don't think it is necessary. Though it is important when it relates to hard drive sizes . This might help you  http://askubuntu.com/questions/172245/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-multiple-computers-something-like-ghost-in-a-easy-w