# A better way to install ubuntu 12.04 on 500 desktops

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on 500 desktops. I want to know what is the better
way to achieve this task. All the machines have same hardware WITHOUT NETWORK.

Comment: Do they have local network? If yes I suggest using [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment). You can configure your own installation server, then via network install all system simultaneously

Comment: Are those 500 desktops the same? (same hard disc etc.) For maintanance: see puppet + puppermaster: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html (that will assume you installed it already though ;) )

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172245/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-multiple-computers-something-like-ghost-in-a-easy-w

Comment: updated my question with some extra information

Comment: Have seen this: [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Comment: @john I would still follow the 'dd'-copy answer in link I posted. All you need is a portable hdd with the 'dd' image on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Preseed* will be good for off-line install:

To Remaster CD see:

[How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Other Preseed Tutorials:

https://pthree.org/2008/05/20/automating-debianubuntu-installs-with-preseed/

https://fak3r.com/2011/08/18/howto-automate-debian-installs-with-preseed/